Confidence interval for ACF plot
Is it possible to modify the straight-line confidence interval that is automatically displayed in the ACF plot in R? Instead of a straight line (Picture 1), I want the CI to be computed at every point, so the CI would most likely be like a (flatter) C (Picture 2). Picture 1 is created in R with the function acf(x).


Edit: acf(x, ci.type = "ma") does the trick.

Can you specify (or link to) what form you would want to use for computing the CI? There is an alternative listed in the ?acf docs, e.g. acf(lh, ci.type = "ma"), that gives expanding CIs which might be what you want. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211628/how-is-the-confidence-interval-calculated-for-the-acf-function https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368404/confidence-intervals-for-autocorrelation-function

That was actually what I came here to post... I had actually tried doing that but it didn't make the difference with my data. Then tried with some toy data and it did. Thanks!

If the question gets reopened you can answer it yourself with this information ...

Solution was easier than I expected...
acf(x, ci.type = "ma")

will do it.
